How should I talk about needing a floor desk in job interviews?
I need to use a floor desk. I can get doctors' notes describing how it's required for my body. How should I mention this requirement during job interviews?

It might be worth adding a few words to explain what a ‘floor desk’ is, for the sake of posterity.  (I'd not heard of one before, and we aim for questions and answers to continue being useful long after image links stop working, and also for those with impaired vision.)

This really needs a country tag. Laws and acceptability of accommodations vary greatly across the globe

@gidds, I see your valid point. However, I was just wondering if people with impaired vision can still read the posts on this site (with the text in a very small font to begin with)... Just wondering...

@Job_September_2020 There are technologies  such as screen readers that can convert text to speech — but are unlikely to do as well with images.  Images are also bigger, not searchable, not very suited to mobile devices…  See this related meta question for some of the issues.

If you have some sort of disability that needs special accommodation, you should refrain from mentioning it during the interview process.
An employer should not be considering these factors during the interview process, and you should not be giving them the opportunity to do so.
Once you have secured your job, it's then you can start discussing any accommodations that you require.

If there is a certain condition or requirement for you to properly conduct your job/ duties, you should bring it up in the initial round of discussions, when the interviewer is done with the questions from their side. Usually, they ask you about any questions you might have for them, and that is the best time to mention requirements like the one you have mentioned.
This is not very uncommon, and they should be happy to accomodate, given they prefer you for the position.

If there is some sort of accommodation required, why would you burden the employer with this information when it may not even be important as they are still considering other candidates?
